# Doing javascript calculations using select dropdown options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math, select

Is it possible to do calculations based on selected options?

Here is my code:

```
    <input type="text" id="resultBox" readonly="true" />
<select id="select1">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: Ya it is possible. But let me ask you: what have you tried?

Comment: definatley possible, lots of jQuery

Comment: @roasted i have tried this:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tmJlE

Comment: @JagtarSingh I've posted modifications would you try this and if it didn't work reply to me

Comment: done some other edits please try it now

Comment: @MuhammadRamahy i am gonna have my lunch break now but i will try after i come back - thanks :)

Comment: ok, I have it worked with me see latest updates :-)

Comment: you can use also matrix (2d dimension array) to do that.
here i created some code for you, maybe it is what you wanted:
http://jsfiddle.net/8rn9y/2/

Answer (score 1):

good but you have some mistakes:
1- you should put if condition between brackets ()
2-what is select1,select2?? these are not defined variable.
3- use alert to know which part of your code doesn't work rather than have long pice of code with abug and you have to chase your tail with it
4- there is no reference on elements in js if you want to set value of text box you need to get this textbox.value and assign new value not to declare a var and play with it, at the end of the day you need to set it yourself

it should be like this

```
    function result() {
  alert("alert");
  var select1_var1;
  var select1_var2;
        var select1Option = document.getElementById("select1").value;
        var select1_control = 10;
        var select2Option = document.getElementById("select2").value;
        var select2_Value = 20;

      if (select1Option = "A"){
        select1_var1 = null;
        select1_var2 = 0;
      }

      if (select2Option = "C"){
        select1_var1 = select2_Value * 50;
        select1_var2 = select2_Value * 100;
      }

      var result = (select1_var1 + select1_var1) / (select1_var2 + select1_var2)

document.getElementById('resultBox').value=result;
}
```

Comment: you can use also matrix (2d dimension array) to do that. here i created some code for you, maybe it is what you wanted: 

http://jsfiddle.net/8rn9y/2

Comment: @zur4ik thanks for your help. i am looking for the simplest way to assign multiple variable. look at the question edit to see what i mean.